# Magento admin menu link stopped working after upgrade

Tags: magento

Before upgradation to `EE v1.12.0.2`, we were running `v1.10.1.1`, at which point this code works fine to add an external link to the menu.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Clean_Integration>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Clean_Integration>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <customer>
                <rewrite>
                    <customer_api>Clean_Integration_Model_Customer_Customer_Api</customer_api>
                </rewrite>
            </customer>
        </models>
        <helpers>
            <coaching>
                <class>Clean_Integration_Helper</class>
            </coaching>
        </helpers>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <Clean_Integration module="Clean_Integration">
                    <file>cleanintegration.xml</file>
                </Clean_Integration>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <adminhtml>
        <menu>
            <coaching translate="title" module="Integration">
                <title>Coaching</title>
                <sort_order>71</sort_order>
                <url>/appointments/sync/backend/</url>
            </coaching>
        </menu>
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <coaching translate="title">
                            <title>Coaching</title>
                        </coaching>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>
        </acl>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

We had a link like `domain.com/appointments/sync/backend/` with this but now with upgrade the menu entry appears but its not a link anymore. So, I am guessing something was changed in Magento which breaks this, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Clean_Integration>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </Clean_Integration>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <customer>
                <rewrite>
                    <customer_api>Clean_Integration_Model_Customer_Customer_Api</customer_api>
                </rewrite>
            </customer>
        </models>
        <helpers>
            <integration>
                <class>Clean_Integration_Helper</class>
            </integration>
        </helpers>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <integration>
                    <file>cleanintegration.xml</file>
                </integration>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <adminhtml>
        <menu>
            <integration translate="title" module="integration">
                <title>Coaching</title>
                <sort_order>71</sort_order>
                <action>appointments/sync/backend/</action>
            </integration>
        </menu>
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <integration translate="title">
                            <title>Coaching</title>
                        </integration>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>
        </acl>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

Create in /app/code/local/Clean/Integration/Helper/Data.php

```
<?php
class Clean_Integration_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract
{

}
```

Take a look @ [Create a sample admin module for form processing](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/how_to_create_an_admin_form_module)

Comment: Tried that too upon which the execution stops at menu, because its looking for the helper file at the wrong place `includes/src/Mage_Integration_Helper_Data.php` instead of `includes/src/Clean_Integration_Helper_Data.php`

Comment: Take a look at my updated code above... you need to add helper. Also is that you entire config or just a section?

Comment: Yep doing exactly like that.

Comment: Exactly like what? what is Mage_Integration_Helper v.s Clean_Integration?. Could you add you entire config.xml

Comment: Exactly like you suggested. I have added my complete `config.xml` now to the question

Comment: Try my updated xml above. Assuming that you clear cache after. Once you get the helper issue resolve then it should work

Comment: Please remember to accept my answer if it work... If you still having issue try adding <models><integration>
                <class>Clean_Integration_Model</class>

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20395/discussion-between-ashfame-and-r-s)

Comment: I edited the answer to reflect the only change which made it to work for me.